# Where do I put C++ Custom Exception Code?

Tags: c++, class, exception, header

I am writing a custom exception for a class I wrote that generates random phrases. I am new to C++ and I am wondering if I am supposed to place the Exception in the Classes header file, in the Classes .cpp file or if I need to split up the declaration and implementation.

Eclipse gives me an error in the main() method that states:

```
error: 'FileException' does not name a type
  } catch (FileException& e) {
```

The Exception Class looks like:

```
class FileException : public std::exception {   
    public:
        const char* what() {
            return "File Could not be opened.";
        }
    }FileException;
```

Any thoughts on the problem would be much appreciated as I am very stuck and confused.

Thanks!

Edit: I should also mention that I am only supposed to submit 2 files, the .cpp file for the class and the .h file

Comment: Do what you'd do for a class that isn't an exception.

Comment: Personally I like using [`std::runtime_error`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error) Instead of custom exceptions as I can give it a custom message at the throw site that will make it easier to figure out why the exception was thrown.

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of the variable (you probably don't need it) or use different names for the class and the variable.

## Explanation:

```
class FileException : public std::exception {
```

`FileException` is a class. Cool.

```
public:
    const char* what() {
        return "File Could not be opened.";
    }
}FileException;
```

that last bit defined a variable of type `FileException` named `FileException` that replaces the `FileException` class. It's the same as defining

```
class FileException : public std::exception {   
public:
    const char* what() {
        return "File Could not be opened.";
    }
};
FileException FileException;
```

The identifier `FileException` now refers to the variable and you can't refer to the class.